# why does jquery select textnodes instead of html element?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
$text = $(unescapedText)
console.log($text)
```

The object I see in the console is a mixture of HTML elements and text nodes:

```
[#text, <div></div>]
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

I know this isnt very descriptive, but this problem happens very inconsistently.

Comment: It happens because you passed a html string that starts with plain text rather than html? in recent versions of jQuery that would throw an error.

Comment: Create a fiddle (maybe in http://www.jsfiddle.net ) to illustrate the issue, this seems unlikely

Comment: what is unescapedText value? string with no html? behaviour of $() depends on type and value of its first argument.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum posting a fiddle wouldnt help because this problem is difficult to predict, even on a single snippet of code

Comment: @fsw `unescapedText` is a string of HTML in this case. But I have observed this problem with plain text as well.

Comment: @codeninja "The problem is difficult to predict" What does that mean? This doesn't sound like a race condition or something too complicated. If you don't have a problem you can explain chances are we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with <tag ... >).
>   If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as
>   explained above.

and according to above:

```
$text = $('blah blah blah');
```

Tries to **select** node "blah" that has at least two "blah" ancestors.
And it is totally different than:

```
$text = $('<blah> blah </blah>');
```

that tries to **create** an element.

This might not be the answer but as you see you need to post some examples of unescapedText and examples of HTML it happens on. Even if it is "difficult to predict". I assume it happened at least once if you are posting this :)